# Load More data by using HTTPURLConnection in java

Tags: twitter, httpurlconnection, twitter4j, httpconnection

In my program , I read data by using HTTPURLConnection for example

```
  URL url = new URL("https://twitter.com/search?q="+kw+"%20lang%3Aeng%20"+"&src=typd&lang=en");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    String html = builder.toString();
```

The problem is only reading data on response page , but I need to read all data that can be retrieved

How I can Load more data in result page

Comment: Why are you using `HttpURLConnection` when you have Twitter API?

Check https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation

Comment: Thanks for response , because twitter api only retrieve data of last week , and the  data that I need during months. Is there any solution to my problem

Comment: You can try Historical API's like https://gnip.com/sources/twitter/historical/ but they may cost you